# How do you change the address of a document library?

Tags: sharepoint, moss, document-library

I have a site with multiple document libraries in it.  One of the site users has full control of the site & at one point, instead of creating a new document library, they renamed the default document library from "Shared Documents" to "Correspondence".  Now they've opened the document library in windows explorer, so it's added an entry into their network places.  The name of the entry was "Shared Documents on portal.mydomain.net" and not "Correspondence on portal.mydomain.net".  This is because the address of the library is still "Shared Documents".  I went into the user's network places and renamed the entry, however I would prefer to have the address changed as well, so that future users do not run into the same problem.

I looked in the Document Library Settings but couldn't find a place to change the address there.  The address gets displayed in "Title, description and navigation" but there is no option to change it.  I tried looking under Site Actions > Site Settings > Content and structure to see if there was any way to change the address there.  However, when I check off the Correspondence document library and pull down the actions menu, "Move" is greyed out.

I *suppose* that I could save the library as a template, include the content & make a new library in the proper address, but then the modified by information would all be wrong.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Renaming the document library in SharePoint Designer changes the address.

Answer (score 1):

Open the library in Windows Explorer, and just rename the folder. Works in Sharepoint Foundation 2010.